# Do I need to get all the Red Dead Redemption achievements to get 100%?

Tags: achievements, red-dead-redemption

I just completed the single player portion of Red Dead Redemption but I am only around 95% complete. I have two Rank 10 tasks to complete (disarm 6 people with no reloads and kill the legendary bears - I've done one bear and the wolf already) but that doesn't seem enough to get 5%. So, what else is there?

I presume some of the achievements lead towards 100% completion (such as breaking all the kinds of horses), but do I need ALL the achievements or is there a subset that must be achieved before I can get 100%?

What else might I be missing? Are there any common tasks that people miss when playing Red Dead Redemption (like an obscure stranger mission or gang hideout)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need every single XBL achievement in order to get 100% completion in Red Dead Redemption. You need to do the following:

- Complete all 57 story missions
- Purchase all 5 rare weapons
- Do the 3 Nightwatch jobs and 2 Horsebreaking jobs at least once
- Unlock all 9 Outfits
- Purchase all 13 player houses
- Complete all 7 gang hideouts
- Complete 20 bounties, doesn't matter if you kill or capture. You need 8 in New Austin, 8 in Mexico, and 4 in West Elizabeth.
- Win at all 6 minigames at least once
- Discover all 94 map locations
- Complete all ranks of Survivalist, Treasure Hunter, Master Hunter, and Sharpshooter challenges (rank I and II)
- Complete 18 Stranger missions (though the *I Know You* one doesn't count towards this, as it is potentially missable)

If you're signed up on [Rockstar's Social Club](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com) website, it keeps track of what you've completed, which I've found to be a great help. It's kind of slow in keeping synched though, but it's awesome for reference.

Comment: Thanks! This is great information. I didn't know it was on Social Club.

Comment: Just a note for those who read this question and own the PS3 version of the game.
The Bollard Twins outfit is an exclusive for the PS3 and doesn't count for the 100% completion in any way.
So ... this makes this list a real accurate 100% completion guide for BOTH systems.

Comment: I have done all that you say that one should do to get the redeemed achivement, stuck on 99,5 %. do not know what i have left. the only thing that i havent done is the Iknow you strangers task.